# jquery undefined issues when using minified version?

Tags: jquery, minify

I've got a core.js file where I include all the critical JS libs and scripts like jQuery which is added in the header of my HTML page. And in the footer I have all my non-critical jQuery plugins and scripts however I keep getting "jQuery undefined" errors from some of these plugins, EVEN though they're wrapped in the jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ... }. When I remove jQuery from the core.js file and link to it within the header separately there is no errors.

```
    <head>
      <script src="core.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

     ....
     ....
       <script src="plugins.js"></script>
    </body>
```

[Core.js (pasetbin)](http://pastebin.com/WTh82D9T)

What gives?

Comment: Can you show how exactly jQuery loading is made within `core.js`?

Comment: Are you including jQuery first. Another plugin may be trying to access the jQuery scripts, this may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just looking at the code, you're not ending the `jQuery.extend()` call properly (line 262), so any plugins after that will not be loaded due to a parse error (ASI doesn't help since the following is all parseable).

Why then the jQuery symbol is not exported to other javascript files is a different matter, but since you say loading it in a separate file helps, this is likely part of the problem.

Comment: Sorry which plugin is that in? Line numbers seem messed up on Pastebin for me :(

Comment: @htmlr hmm my editor must have converted some lines. It's the UI Grid definition that was giving me trouble (I believe in pastebin it's line 255).